# Flutter - MultiProvider (ChangeNotifierProvider) doesn't work

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-change-notifier

ChangeNotifierProvider doesn't work! I don't know what is the problem. 
Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?
Thank you

I want to pass the **test** value  to the next page.

Here is the main function and the providers

```
void main() {
runApp(
MultiProvider(
providers:[
ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductsNotifier>(create:(context)=> ProductsNotifier()),
//  second provider...
],
child:MaterialApp( home: MyApp())
)  
);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Provider
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Test'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child:RaisedButton(
    onPressed: (){
    ProductsNotifier obj = new ProductsNotifier();
    obj.testFun();
      Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
        );
      },
      child: Text('GO TO THE NEXT PAGE'),
    )
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Next Page:

```
class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var txt = Provider.of<ProductsNotifier>(context);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Next Page'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Text(txt.test.toString()),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Class ProductsNotifier

```
class ProductsNotifier with ChangeNotifier{
String _test ;
String get test => _test;

 void testFun()  {
 _test = "DONE!";
  notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove this line:

```
ProductsNotifier obj = new ProductsNotifier();
```

It is already created here:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductsNotifier>(create:(context)=> ProductsNotifier()),
```

Then

```
class ProductsNotifier with ChangeNotifier{
```

replace with:

```
class ProductsNotifier extends ChangeNotifier{
```

Comment: Ahaaa, Thank you 
I am a new in flutter so I did not understand it very well.
Now, I got it. thank you again.